# Duplicate word typo on Careers in "Add Project"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

> Use this form for software **projects
>   projects** that you created or
>   contributed to. This may include app
>   store apps, commercial software,
>   shareware...

Found on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/project/{userid}.

[image: Pizza piz-- projects projects!]

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the hilariously-poignant pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now - thanks for the heads-up!